# Какой метод нужно использовать для кодирования сообщения, которое ввел пользователь? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю программу на WindowsForms, которая кодирует сообщение из букв в цифры (1 или 0)

Мне нужно считать строку, введенную пользователем в первый текст-бокс, разделить ее на символы для проверки (Типа: если первый символ = А, то вместо А в выводе второго текст-бокса - 1, и т.д.).

Я пробовал через массив, но это очень долго))) помогите, пожалуйста))

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Text_Encoder_v1._0
{
    public partial class Text_Encoder_Form : Form
    {
        public Text_Encoder_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Это кнопка, которая при нажатии кодирует сообщение, если пользователь ввел что-то
        private void button_StartProg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox_InputText.Text != "")
            {
                // Если пользователь ввел что-то, то это запишется в переменную
                string text = textBox_InputText.Text;

                // Вот, дальше я эту строку разбиваю на массив символов
                char[] text_chars = text.ToCharArray();

                /* Дальше я проверяю по индексам массива содержание текста, который ввел пользователь
                 * Но это будет очень долго и производительность будет не та!
                 * Как это можно улучшить?
                 */
               switch (text_chars[0])
               {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                        textBox_OutputText.Text = "1";
                        break;

                    case 'B':
                    case 'b':
                        textBox_OutputText.Text = "0";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не знаете как написать функцию перекодирования или как запустить эту функцию по клику на кнопку?

Comment: Мне нужна функция, которая перекодирует сообщение. мне просто интересно, как это сделать? я пробовал через массив(т.е делил строку на массив символов, потом проверял элементы массива, но у меня ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать называется "[шифр подстановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)", известен издревле, поддаётся атаке по частоте символов. Ну да ладно, смотрите.

Вам нужен словарь какой символ на какой менять:

```
Dictionary<char, char> mapping = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    {'A', 'Ы'},
    {'r', '!'},
    // и т.д. и т.п.
};
```

Напишем простую функцию, которая в цикле пройдёт все символы и заменит их на новые (а если замены нет - оставит как есть):

```
public string EncodeString(string source, Dictionary<char, char> mapping)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if(mapping.ContainsKey(element))
        {
            sb.Append(mapping[element]);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(element);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Ну и всё, пользуемся:

```
var source = "CrackMe!";

Dictionary<char, char> mapping = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    {'A', 'Ы'},
    {'r', '!'},
};

var result = this.EncodeString(source, mapping);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вообще, это можно сделать и в linq, но расписываю самый базовый вариант.

Если хотите - можете переделать не замену строго символ на символ, а символ на строку или строку на строку.

Comment: Большое спасибо!))) если честно, не особо понял, в общем, просто скопирую, вставлю, пойду разбираться))))

Comment: А как будет выглядеть функция, которая будет из зашифрованного сообщения переделывать обратно в буквы и соединять их в строки для вывода?